# odata api: not all properties are returned to the caller of the api

Tags: c#, api, odata

I have a `PeopleController` and currently I have a problem with the `Addresses` property found in `AddressesList` class. When I call the API from Postman or any other client, the `AddressesList` property is null even though there are values. I see them when I debug the API, but they are not returned to the caller. Only value returned is `BNumber`.

This happens when I introduced `[Key]` attribute on the `DocNumber` property in the `WorkAddress` class.

```
public class Person
{
    public AddressesList Addresses { get; set; }
    public string BNumber { get; set; }
}

public class AddressesList
{
    public WorkAddress[] WorkAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class WorkAddress
{
    [Key]
    public string DocNumber { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public Unit[] DocUnits {get;set;}
}

public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Person> Get()
{
    // ...
    return v.AsQueryable();
}
```

If I remove the `[Key]` attribute, the all properties are returned, but not when I add the `[Key]` attribute again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Perhaps if you can share your webapiconfig, will be helpful.
PS: Try to declare them as complex types in config.